# How to fetch immediate next/previous text from regular expression

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have a long string with same text coming multiple times. Similar to 'id' parameter in below string:

```
id="left" class="pr" id="wrap" id="main" id="wrapper" id="logo_wrapper" class="standard_logo_wrapper mb24" h1 style="height: 100%; display: table-cell; vertical-align: bottom;" img id="logo" class="standard_logo"
```

While fetching value of last 'id' parameter `[id=logo]` using regular expression as `[id="(.+?)" class="standard_logo"]` provides me with complete string as mentioned below instead of only "logo" text:

```
left" class="pr" id="wrap" id="main" id="wrapper" id="logo_wrapper" class="standard_logo_wrapper mb24" h1 style="height: 100%; display: table-cell; vertical-align: bottom;" img id="logo"
```

Kindly let me know what regular expressions can be used to handle such cases.

Comment: `[id="(.+?)" class="standard_logo"]` - some specific regex tool?

Comment: Thanks Roman, I have just updated the question. earlier it was missing some information due to html tags

Comment: Moreover, your expression is giving me each character separately which is not what i am looking for

Comment: You should look into backreferences (`$1` or `\1`) which give you the part that was captured in parentheses only..

Comment: You need to set the template to `$1$` and use a pattern like `id="([^"]*)" class="standard_logo"`

Comment: @RaviSharma, *your expression is giving me* - I've cited your expression, asking about your current regex tool. It was not solution

Comment: please add screenshot of regular expression extractor

Comment: Thank you all for looking into this issue, I have tried Wiktor's answer and it worked for me